# Why am I getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error when I try to switch activities in studio?

Tags: java, android

I've tried to look up whats causing this but I can't find out why this is happening- I'm setting up an on click listener to have a button switch activies. I'm not getting any error popups however when I run the app it crashes and logcat shows im getting a java.lang.NullPointerException on the listener itself. Here's the code-

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainTypesBtn);



    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainTypes.class));
        }
    });




    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);
}
```

I'm getting the error on  `btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

MainTypes is the second activity and has nothing in it.

Comment: move the btn initialization and the setOnClickListener after setContetView. Here the order maters

Comment: you must initialise or provide any listener to the views after the `setContentView`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);
```

goes right after:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

then you make:

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainTypesBtn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainTypes.class));
    }
});
```

and Second detail:

**LoadingScreen** is not your current Activity... is **MainScreen**

Comment: 1 upvote for mentioning MainScreen instead of LoadingScreen

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `findViewById()` before `setContentView()`. try this:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainTypesBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainTypes.class));
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainTypesBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainTypes.class));
        }
    });
}
```

actually `setContentView` did that magic, in `setContentView` method your button will create. before that its just null

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is not set yet when you initialize the button. So at first you need to set layout and then initialize the button that can resolve your problem.Try the following:`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainTypesBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          startActivity(new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainTypes.class));
        }
    });
}`
```